# Cleanup a git rebase (should have git pull'd)

Tags: git, rebase

I'm doing a git rebase from a branch, where I picked up 3 changes but rebased like 10, I really wish I had used git pull.  I guess I am s[till learning git.  The changes were published...

I'd rather have done a git pull, so only the 3 checkins are added to the upper branch rather than rebaseing the dozen or so commits in the upper branch.

Is there a way to clean this up?  Or just move on.  Github won't let me back out the commit, probably for good reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always just reset back to the state you were at before the rebase and then do a pull instead - use `git reflog` to figure out the hash that you used to be at before the rebase, and then use `git reset --hard <sha>` to reset your branch to that SHA. Then do the git pull normally. Once you're to the state you'd prefer to be at, you can push back to github using the `--force` flag.

You may want to make a backup of your `.git` folder first, just in case.